# How to modify all ASP.NET controls to inherit from my special control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

TextBox, Label, Panel, ... all inherits from `Control`.

Is there a way to inherit from `Control` and make ASP.NET controls inherit from my new control?

For example, I have a control

```
public class SpecialControl : Control
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want all controls to inherit from it, so

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" Something="hello" />
```

Would be valid.

Comment: Try out to update web.config Controls section by providing an other assembly association for tagPrefix="asp", but I'm not sure whether it will update code behind classes as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the inheritance chain of the controls that are part of the BCL.

Comment: yeah, you would need the source code of the actual controls, change the inheritance, and recompile.  But as far as I know, the source code of the built in controls is not public/available.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to create an extension method as below.

```
<asp:TextBox id="tst" runat="server" Something="TestValue"></asp:TextBox> 

 public static string GetSomething(this WebControl value)
{
   return value.Attributes["Something"].ToString();
}
```

I only tested this for a `TextBox` control. May not be the ideal solution as it is not strongly typed but will work.

Comment: This is not really what I need, but is actually very interesting. +1

Answer (score 0):

As Oded mentioned, you can't modify the inheritance chain of packaged controls.

What you can do is create wrappers for the packaged controls, and implement custom properties and methods in the wrappers. Here's a simple example of how to extend the TextBox:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomTextBox runat=server></{0}:CustomTextBox>")]
public class CustomTextBox: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Something
    {
        get
        {
            string something = (string)ViewState["Something"];
            return (something == null) ? String.Empty : something ;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Something"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(Text);
    }
}
```